# NumPy is behaving irregularly when values are printed to the console

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very simple **Python** script that uses `numpy`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

defaultdict(partial(np.ndarray, 10))
boolean = np.array([x % 2 == 0 for x in xrange(10)])
genes = defaultdict(partial(np.ndarray, 10))

print np.array(boolean)
print genes['no-data']
```

which gives the output:

```
[ True False  True False  True False  True False  True False]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

This seems to work as expected. However if I simply comments out the `print np.array(boolean)` I get the output:

```
[  3.10503618e+231   3.10503618e+231   2.22343947e-314   2.22346872e-314
   2.22346870e-314   2.22346875e-314   2.22354680e-314   2.22354683e-314
   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
```

This seems completely odd to me because the two statements *should* have nothing to do with each other.

**Does anyone have any idea why I could be getting the second set of (*incorrect*) numbers?**

Comment: The values could be anything in the array, if you run it under python3 you will see random values each call, I can replicate the behaviour using python2 though, the print always affects the output.

Comment: How would I initialize the values to `0` then? I had thought `defaultdict` did that, but I guess not.

Comment: why not just `genes = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(10))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are not incorrect.  You are creating an *uninitialized* array.  The contents of the memory are whatever happens to be in the memory allocated for the array.  It is not guaranteed to be 0.

If you want the array to be initialized with 0s, use `np.zeros`:

```
In [35]: genes = defaultdict(partial(np.zeros, 10))

In [36]: genes['no-data']
Out[36]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [37]: genes['foo']
Out[37]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Although, like @PadraicCunningham suggested in a comment, I'd get rid of the import of `functools` and use a `lambda` expression instead:

```
In [38]: genes = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(10))

In [39]: genes['no-data']
Out[39]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [40]: genes['foo']
Out[40]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Hmmm...the `defaultdict` doesn't initialize a with a default?

Comment: You have `genes` set up to call `ndarray(10)` when `genes` is indexed with a nonexistent key.  The memory allocated for the array returned by `ndarray(10)` is not initialized, so there is no guarantee of the contents.

Comment: `ndarray` is a specialized way of creating an array, too 'high powered' for everyday use. `zeros`, `ones`, `empty` are more user friendly.